# Encrypting and decrypting part of the ASCII table

Tags: c++, c, rot13

I have made small encryption program that uses to keys rot7 and rot13. Everything works fine except two 6 letters uvwxyz.

If I type ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ  it encrypts and decrypts no problem. However, if I enter the same in lower case letters then uvwxyz do not work.

Having said this, I have allowed all the writable characters within the ascii table as the valid range as follows:

```
// allow all writable characters from 32 to 255
if ((str[i] >= 32 ) && (str[i] <=255))
{
    str[i] -= key;
}
```

Here is the process of encryption:

```
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Encrypting process started " << endl << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------- " << endl;

    //get the string length
    int i = 0;
    int length = str.length();
    int key = rot13 ;
    int k = 5;
    int multiple = 0;
    int count = 0;

    cout << "the text to encrypt is: " << str << endl;
    cout << "text length is: " << length << endl; 
    cout << "using rot13"<<endl;
    cout <<"---------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "using rot13" << endl;

    //traverse the string
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {

        count ++;

       cout << left;

       //if it is a multiple of 5 not the first character change the key 
        if((multiple = (( i % 5 ) == 0)) && (count != 1)  && (key == rot13)){

            key = rot7;


        }
        //if it is a multiple of 5 not the first character change the key 
        else if((multiple = (( i % 5 ) == 0)) && (count != 1) && (key == rot7) ) {

            key = rot13;


        }


        // Capital letters are 65 to 90  (a - z)
        if ((str[i] >= 32) && (str[i] <= 255))
        {
            str[i] += key;
        }


    }
    return str;
```

How is it possible that the capital letters work and not the lower case if I have allowed this range? Can it be because of something else? I have added these captures with what happens step by step... hopefully this helps

Comment: Can you show us it not working?

Comment: sure I can I am going to edit and put up a capture

Comment: Um, I meant just show us the full code and the output it's giving you.

Comment: sure I can add the code as well...

Comment: @sftrabbit there you go... the decrypting is the same only reversing the keys.

Answer (score 4):

In your code :

```
    if ((str[i] >= 32) && (str[i] <= 255))
        {
           if (str[i] + key > 255)
               str[i] = ((str[i] + key) % 255 )+ 32;
           else
               str[i] += key;
        }
```

if `key` has a value of 13 and `str[i]` is 'u' or greater, `str[i]` has a value higher than 255.

You should use modulo `%` operator in this case, this is rotation, not only a shift

Comment: something like this?  range str[i] = (str[i] + key) % character_range;

Comment: 255 + 32 kinda. Try to wrote the value of strings so you can observe it yourself. As a int by the way.

Comment: You have to test the sum of your value because, you have to had 32 only in case of going higher than 255.